# Ubuntu on new PC with not-yet-configured Windows 7

Tags: 14.04

I bought a refurbished HP Z400 workstation with Windows 7, which is not set up and configured yet. I want to replace it with Ubuntu. Do I have to configure Windows first or I can just insert the Ubuntu installation disk and take it from there? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine just booting from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and installing as if the machine had an empty hard disk.  Select a custom install, and use the partitioning tool to create a new partition table (which will erase everything on the hard disk), create your desired partition layout, and continue the installation.  Or, select "Install using the entire hard disk" which will automatically do the same thing, with Ubuntu's default hard disk layout.